# Does python list store the object or the reference to the object?

Tags: python, list

Size of an **integer is 24 bytes** and **size of a char is 38 bytes,** but when i insert into a list the size of the list doesn't reflect the exact size of the object that i insert. So, now I am wandering list is holding the reference of the object and the object is storing somewhere in memory.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof('a')
38
>>> sys.getsizeof([])
72
>>> sys.getsizeof([1])
80
>>> sys.getsizeof(['a'])
80
>>> sys.getsizeof('james') 
42
>>>
```

Comment: All objects in python are stored as references, so the distinction is meaningless.

Comment: So, reference means the value return by id(object) right, if so >>> id(1)
140338077434280
>>>                                                                       >>> sys.getsizeof(140338077434280)
24
>>>

Comment: Could you explain it properly ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All values in Python are boxed, they don't map to machine types or sizes. Namely everything in the implementation of CPython is a `PyObject` struct.

http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#PyObject

> So, now I am wandering list is holding the reference of the object and the object is storing somewhere in memory.

A list is also a PyObject that contains a [sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html) of references to other PyObjects for the elements of the list. The list is allocated on the Python heap that is managed by the Python garbage collector.

Comment: If you have some familiarity with C then the documentation of the Python C-API is in general quite good: http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html

Answer (score 2):

Everything in python is stored as reference. So your assumption is right.

```
>>> id(1)
10274744
>>> a = [1]
>>> id(a)
11037512
>>> id(a[0])
10274744
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
80
```

You see that the a[0] points to the id/address of 1. This shows that only the reference to the object is stored in the list.

Comment: So, what actually does the list is holding ? the value of id()

Comment: @yopy: Yes the reference id is stored in the list

Comment: Careful! `id`s of integer constants are not guaranteed to be equal, and indeed, for integers as large as 257, they aren't. (try `id(257) == id(258 - 1)`)

Comment: but the size of the id is 24 bytes                                            >>> sys.getsizeof(140338077434280)
24
>>>

Comment: @AswinMurugesh `the a[0] points to the id/address of 1` but what actually is stored inside a[0], i confirmed is not the value of id(a[0])

Comment: @yopy: In the sense you seem to mean, what is "actually" stored in `a[0]`  is something you cannot access or manipulate in any way.  `a[0]` evaluates to a Python object, and that is all you can rely on.  You cannot access or manipulate the "pointer" itself, or get the actual memory address where the list contents are stored, or anything like that.